How to generate a right power-law noise?
I want to generate power-law noise. I have used some code to do this, but I found the generated series have strong correlation between the first sample and the last.

You can see when I just fix the first sample to zero the last also tends to be around zero. I can't believe this, but it also happens when using other code like this:https://github.com/felixpatzelt/colorednoise
I have some idea about how it happens, but I'm not sure. When I use a DFT to generate noise, the discrete series is regarded to be periodic. So R(N-1) = R(-1)=R(1)(R means correlation).
My question is: Is this result true? Or can it happen to real power-law noise? If it's wrong, how to generate a true power-law noise.
This is my code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sim_noise_spec(nsamp, dt=1, fknee=0.1, alpha=3, sigma=1):
    freq   = np.abs(np.fft.fftfreq(nsamp, dt))
    return (1+(np.maximum(freq,freq[2])/fknee)**-alpha)*sigma**2


N_sim = 100
nsamp = 100000
noise_spec = sim_noise_spec(nsamp, dt=.02, fknee=.215, alpha=3, sigma=1)

for i_sim in range(N_sim):
    rand   = np.fft.fft(np.random.standard_normal(nsamp))
    fnoise = rand * noise_spec**0.5
    tod_noise = np.fft.ifft(fnoise).real
    tod_noise -= tod_noise[0]

    plt.plot(tod_noise)

plt.title('100 1/f Noise simulations(t=0 fix on zero)')
plt.show()


Welcome to our SE. It would help if you would label your axes and if you put some comments in your code.

Welcome to DSP.SE!  I believe Ed V's post here answers your question: Pink ($1/f$) pseudo-random noise generation. If you agree - please give him an upvote. I'm voting to close this question due to the duplication but please don't take any offense by that. Keep the questions coming!


My question is: Is this result true?

True in the sense that it inevitably flows from your code.  It's probably not a reflection of any real system, however.

but I found the generated series have strong correlation between the first sample and the last.  ...  You can see when I just fix the first sample to zero the last also tends to be around zero.

This is an artifact of simulating a low-pass noise process with an FFT.  The FFT takes a spectrum and renders it as a collection of sine waves each one of which puts an integer number of cycles into the output vector.  The last sample will be highly correlated with the first, because you are only using the low-frequency part of the spectrum.

<Or> can it happen to real power-law noise? If it's wrong, how to generate a true power-law noise.

Yes and no.  The characteristic of the noise starting at 0 and growing will happen any time you constrain the first sample to be zero -- so yes.  But the characteristic "wrapping around" back to zero again will only happen with the FFT -- so no.
If you want to generate true power-law noise that looks right in the time domain, delete the line that says tod_noise -= tod_noise[0].  Then your first sample will be any random value (which is sensible) and your expected amplitude will be constant (which is also sensible).

